# Designing by the grid 1140px

Tags: grids

I'm using a theme based on 1140px grid and I'd like to make the content area narrower while making the sidebar wider (currently it's 250px). How do I ensure everything stays proportional? I'm looking at something in the region of 300px for the sidebar.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are actually asking here? The column proportions are going to change if you change their widths while keeping the overall width the same.

Comment: Yeah but there are ways to have 2 columns on the same grid, but of varying widths. My question is how will I know what these combinations are for 2 columns.

Comment: If you increase one column by 50px in a two-column layout of fixed width, you need to take 50px off the other column.

Comment: To clarify what e100 said in comment #1: if you make the column wider and the content area narrower, they cannot "stay proportional." Perhaps you can reconsider the wording of your question.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the grid. Think in terms of grid units, not specific pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you aren't happy with the theme and you need something new.

**[Gridpak](http://gridpak.com/) is an excellent responsive grid generator** that may save you a lot of pain and suffering. Enter your column count, padding, gutters, and simply drag a pixel-snapped ruler to set the total size then download your files.

[image: Gridpak]

**[Gridset](https://gridsetapp.com/) is a more in-depth, professional grade responsive grid generator.** If you're up for that, this one will also cost you a little ([very little](https://gridsetapp.com/pricing/)). I haven't used it since private beta but it produced beautiful responsive code then.

[image: Gridset]